# Access a webservice API from PHP and store results in a database

Tags: php, web-services, rest, cordova

I am writing here because am confused with what information I gathered on the topic I am going to discuss..

There is a phonegap app which had a backend server previously, and it is now removed. So, the client is trying to use a new webservice API (RESTful service) which gives the desired results. The complete requirement of the client is:

1. Make the app work using new webservice API.
2. Use an intermediate server app that invokes the new webservice API only once in a day.
3. The end-users (mobile app users) should get data from the intermediate server. NOT from the webservice API directly.

The result produced by the webservice API is JSON. Now it needs to be handled at the intermediate server and the result should be stored in a database (MySQL, MSSQL or any other). whenever mobile app user requests data, result should be retrieved from the intermediate server. This server gets data from the webservice API periodically.

For this I understood that PHP could be a better option to connect to the webservice API. I tried to get through this http://blog.ijasoneverett.com/2013/02/rest-api-a-simple-php-tutorial/

Can anyone help me getting a full working example of such a scenario? I am comfortable with accessing the data from Server to mobile device but I am not sure how to establish a connection between the Server and the webservice API.

Kindly let me know if I need to provide more inputs here.

Comment: Why is the intermediate server needed? (distribute load?) cUrl could be an option: http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Comment: Are you able to create json service file in php?

Comment: @Delpes - the data displayed within the app is not so dynamic. I mean, the data changes once in every 1 or 2 days. So it may not make sense accessing the webservice API (third party paid service) from mobile everytime. And for that reason, an intermediate server is placed... this server retrieves data from the service and stores it in a database (owned by client). So a mobile user hits the Server, and NOT the service directly avoiding unnecessary costs.

Comment: @Ved - no, I am not sure on how to do that. I am confused there. But I know how to handle a JSON output produced by the PHP file, and then push the data into a database.

Comment: Use this carefully only PHP part for your use: 1) http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: hi @Ved.. thanks for sending me the link. I've gone through it. I think I should be more clear here.. the problem I have is "how to connect to a webservice API using PHP, to retrieve data produced by the webservice API, and then store it in a database?".
I am very much comfortable with PHP-> database and the CRUD operations.